# Why am I getting «delete of Steam.exe failed, Win32 Error 5 "Access is denied"»?

Tags: steam

My PC is running Windows 7. I tried installing Steam. I downloaded the program. When I attempt to run it, it loads about half way and gives me an error message:

> Steam.exe (main exception): ERROR delete of Steam.exe failed, Win32 Error 5 "Access is denied"

I have no idea why this would happen and cannot find any answers anywhere online or among my friends or colleagues. I've never had any problems with Steam before. I would greatly appreciate any help or advice given.

Comment: Have you tried running the installation file as an administrator?

Comment: Try right-clicking and choosing "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a lot as well. Remove steam, reinstall it, then run the setup as admin.